# SohCahToa Project

Tags: java, bluej

I need some help with a project I'm working on the side to help me in my physics and chemistry class.

This is the code that I have produced so far and it seems to give me an answer that are incorrect for all trials I have given it. All help is appreciated!

```
public double sinSinUnknown(double opp, double hyp)
{
    double sin = 0;
    sin = Math.asin((opp / hyp));
    return sin;
}

public double sinOppUnknown(double sin, double hyp)
{
    double opp = 0;
    opp = Math.sin(sin) * hyp;
    return opp;
}

public double sinHypUnknown(double sin, double opp)
{
    double hyp = 0;
    hyp = opp / Math.sin(sin);
    return hyp;
}

public double cosCosUnknown(double adj, double hyp)
{
    double cos = 0;
    cos = Math.acos((adj / hyp));
    return cos;
}

public double cosAdjUnknown(double cos, double hyp)
{
    double adj = 0;
    adj = hyp * Math.cos(cos);
    return adj;
}

public double cosHypUnknown(double cos, double adj)
{
    double hyp = 0;
    hyp = adj / Math.cos(cos);
    return hyp;
}

public double tanTanUnknown(double opp, double adj)
{
    double tan = 0;
    tan = Math.atan((opp / adj));
    return tan;
}

public double tanOppUnknown(double tan, double adj)
{
    double opp = 0;
    opp = adj * Math.tan(tan);
    return opp;
}

public double tanAdjUnknown(double tan, double opp)
{
    double adj = 0;
    adj = opp / Math.tan(tan);
    return adj;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm going to guess that you aren't expecting the angles to be in radians...

Comment: It would be good if you can explain what is "incorrect for all trials". Provide some examples

Comment: I should have provided examples and I will for my next question, and I was expecting it to not be in radians, but thank you for your feed back!

Answer (score 0):

The trigonometric functions in [java.lang.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) require inputs in radians, rather than degrees. This can be done using the [toRadians](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) function.

You'll need to convert your answers back to degrees, using the [toDegrees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees-double-) function.

```
public double sinSinUnknown(double opp, double hyp)
{
    double sin = 0;
    sin = Math.asin((Math.toRadians(opp) / Math.toRadians(hyp)));
    return Math.toDegrees(sin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!